# pros/cons of defining methods inside of stateless components

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a (somewhat contrived component) like this

```
    const ExampleComponent = (props) => {
    const renderList = () => {
        if (props.list) {
            props.list.map((item) => <ListItem {...props.list} />);
        } else {
            return <div>List Not Found </div>
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <H1>LIST VIEW</H1>
            {renderList()}
        </div>
    )
};
```

Is React going to reinitialize that function on every render tick? Should I be worried about that or is it a negligible detail.

Would it be considered to write my component as

```
const renderList = (list) => {
    if (list) {
        list.map((item) => <ListItem {...list} />);
    } else {
        return <div>List Not Found </div>
    }
};

const ExampleComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <H1>LIST VIEW</H1>
            {renderList(props.list)}
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: Its good to be thinking about performance. Most people say wait until you have an issue before addressing it. However, I'd say if you want to be conscious of performance and not need to refactor later, then yes define the methods outside of the component. Or use a class :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just read a little bit of this: http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

> "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

Answering to your questions:

**Is React going to reinitialize that function on every render tick?** Yup, that function will be re-declared on every render.

**Should I be worried about that or is it a negligible detail.** Don't worry about that.

Comment: Yah I realize it's not a huge deal, I was just kind of curious as to how the Node interpreter would handle this.